# DataFrame.save() / sqlContext.load loses "nullable" status of schema

Tags: apache-spark

I have a couple of questions based on something I am seeing on spark-shell. The easiest thing is just to show the behavior:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql._
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
scala> val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("foo", IntegerType, false)))
scala> val df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Array(Row(1))), schema)
scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = false)
scala> df1.save("temp.parq", SaveMode.Overwrite)
scala> val df2 = sqlContext.load("temp.parq")
scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = true)
```

Note that the nullable property for column "foo" changed.

I ran into issues with nullable columns when I turned on spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown and that's when I noticed this behavior.

So my questions:

1. Do I really care about this?
2. If yes, then how can I tell whether the
   change to the schema happens before or after the save to Parquet
   file?

Comment: I've seen somewhere in the source code that schema get from parquet are regarded as nullable whatever the origin value is in parquet. I mean, the nullable was lost when reading from parquet file. I tried to find that piece of code for you but can't find it, may be fixed in the master branch now

Comment: Hmm, but just because nullable is lost on read doesn't mean it isn't also lost on write. It matters because, like I said, I discovered the behavior in relation to an error relating to filterPushdown, which specifically has a warning in the documentation about null values causing issues.

Comment: FilterPushDown may not be at a stable state now.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. Luckily volume testing my app is a ways out, and at any rate with Parquet file partitioning I can probably survive just even that much longer with out FilterPushDown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at source code of new spark 1.3+, you found the next comment:

```
  // This is a hack. We always set nullable/containsNull/valueContainsNull to true
  // for the schema of a parquet data
```

for example:

```
    /** Returns a new base relation with the given parameters and save given data into it. */
  override def createRelation(
      sqlContext: SQLContext,
      mode: SaveMode,
      parameters: Map[String, String],
      data: DataFrame): BaseRelation = {
    val path = checkPath(parameters)
    val filesystemPath = new Path(path)
    val fs = filesystemPath.getFileSystem(sqlContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    val doInsertion = (mode, fs.exists(filesystemPath)) match {
      case (SaveMode.ErrorIfExists, true) =>
        sys.error(s"path $path already exists.")
      case (SaveMode.Append, _) | (SaveMode.Overwrite, _) | (SaveMode.ErrorIfExists, false) =>
        true
      case (SaveMode.Ignore, exists) =>
        !exists
    }

    val relation = if (doInsertion) {
      // This is a hack. We always set nullable/containsNull/valueContainsNull to true
      // for the schema of a parquet data.
      val df =
        sqlContext.createDataFrame(
          data.queryExecution.toRdd,
          data.schema.asNullable,
          needsConversion = false)
      val createdRelation =
        createRelation(sqlContext, parameters, df.schema).asInstanceOf[ParquetRelation2]
      createdRelation.insert(df, overwrite = mode == SaveMode.Overwrite)
      createdRelation
    } else {
      // If the save mode is Ignore, we will just create the relation based on existing data.
      createRelation(sqlContext, parameters)
    }

    relation
  }
}
```

I think that's what you're looking for. I don’t know the reason of this behaviour. But it was really surprising for me.

Comment: Thanks. I honestly do not think this would not be a big deal -- a DataFrame is read-only and nullable is meaningless for a DataFrame you loaded from file -- except that if you save the DF or one built from its columns you will lose the nullable status of the original column.